# TinyMCE, Responsive File Manager виджет не показывается. Отображается как textarea

Tags: yii2, плагин, tinymce

Я пытался установить плагин responsive Filemanager для tinymce на yii2 фреймворке.
https://github.com/xvs32x/tinymce-responsivefilemanager

Проблема в том, что виджет отображается в виде обычного textarea

У людей уже была такая ошибка, но человек её решивший ничего не объяснил, вот ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515603/tinymce-responsive-file-manager-not-showing-up

Мой код:

```
$form->field($model, 'text')->widget(Tinymce::className(), [
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'plugins' => [
                        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                        "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
                    ],
                    'theme' => 'modern',
                    'setup' => new JsExpression("function(editor){
                            editor.on('change', function () {
                            editor.save();
                        });
                    }"),
                    'toolbar1' => "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
                    'toolbar2' => "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor ",
                    'image_advtab' => true,
                    'external_filemanager_path' => "/filemanager/",
                    'filemanager_title' => "Responsive Filemanager",
                    'external_plugins' => ["filemanager" => "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"],
                    'language' => 'ru',
                ],
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Может проблема в том, что не правильный путь до класса?
\xvs32x\tinymce\Tinymce::className() - он в примере был таким, или ты использовал use?

И зачем setup в опциях? Попробую полностью воспользоваться с примером.

Могу только от себя ещё добавлять textarea и не создается, приходится создавать textarea самому и при создании виджета делать такое же имя.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).